# Event manager error after upgrading my WSP via Update-SPSolution

Tags: development, event-receivers

So I just deployed this .wsp to production and I've identified a tiny bit of logic that needs tweaking in an event receiver. I'm considering compiling a new .wsp package, and then running an Update-SPSolution on my production SPF. Naturally, I just wanted to verify that such an update would actually work. So, here's my context:

I still have a development SPF with the same version of the solution running identical to production. The only difference was, the development version was deployed via Visual Studio (as is common, I suppose).

Then, I made some minor tweaks to a list event receiver code. I updated the Assembly version, built the solution and then packaged it up (but did not use Visual Studio to deploy it). Rather I ran the **Update-SPSolution** command. All seems well enough. No errors in the console.

Now, when I go to perform action X which should cause the event receiver to fire.. it doen't fire at all. Instead, I see this in the ULS:

> Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly 'myCustomAssembly,
>   Version=1.0.1.14, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=130eeb2d789a2e4b' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So, it's hanging on to the old Version=1.0.1.14 when my latest .wsp contains Version=1.0.2.0

Is the **Update-SPSolution** really so worthless? I read somewhere on MSDN it's supposed to be for these situations where all the files and features between solutions are still-present (though containing changes). I've done upgrades in the past where I had to deactivate-features, uninstall, re-install.. and I'm really hoping to execute something less intrusive.

### **EDIT:**

FWIW: When I comb the log for critical-level errors, I also see this one. I don't take all the errors on my DEV box *too* seriously.. but I am noticing a pattern.. this one is always coupled with the aforementioned one:

> An exception occurred while updating addresses for connected app
>   {7a59242d-4587-4f4e-9563-e067aa23c5e7_61322854-9714-4458-949c-c2bcc98ef497}.
>   The uri endpoint information may be stale.
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The requested application could not
>   be found.     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplicationProxy.ProcessCommonExceptions(Uri
>   endpointAddress, String operationName, Exception ex,
>   SPServiceLoadBalancerContext context)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplicationProxy.ExecuteOnChannel(String
>   operationName, CodeBlock codeBlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPTopologyWebServiceApplicationProxy.GetEndPoints(Guid
>   serviceId)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPConnectedServiceApplicationAddressesRefreshJob.Execute(Guid
>   targetInstanceId)

Comment: I have chosen to accept-as-answer the response from @almostSharepointMaster as an exhaustive treatment to my proposed question. Even though, I'm still not quite sure why I can't get Update-Solution to work for my particular scenario. I'll keep updating this thread if I ever discover further detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Update-SPSolution –Identity YourSolutionName.wsp –LiteralPath “C:\YourSolutionName.wsp” –GacDeployment
```

This should update the existing wsp with the new version with the correct version!

> The Update-SPSolution cmdlet upgrades a deployed SharePoint solution
>   in the farm. Use this cmdlet only if a new solution contains the same
>   set of files and features as the deployed solution. If files and
>   features are different, the solution must be retracted and redeployed
>   by using the Uninstall-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution cmdlets,
>   respectively.

[How do I update an already existing wsp on farm?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45675/how-do-i-update-an-already-existing-wsp-on-farm)

**EDIT**

If you have an issue as you have you will notice that just upgrading isnt enough thats becasue you have changed the versioning ;) so you would need to do the following to ask sharepoint to go through the list of features to upgrade :):

open cmd (command propmt)

trype in the following:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -wait
```

> Performs an upgrade of SharePoint 2010 Products. This command is
>   automatically run when you run the SharePoint Products Configuration
>   Wizard if the product has to be upgraded.

**How to use Psconfig commands**

> When you run Psconfig at a command prompt, you can specify commands to
>   control how the tool runs. To run Psconfig at a command prompt,
>   navigate to the %COMMONPROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Shared\web server
>   extensions\14\bin folder, and then type the commands by using the
>   following syntax:

```
psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -wait
```

the following is describing the commands :)

```
[-wait]
```

If specified, the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard does not return until the upgrade is complete. If not specified, the wizard returns after dispatching a SharePoint Timer Service job to perform the upgrade. To view the upgrade job status, you can access the SharePoint Central Administration Web site by using your Web browser.

```
[-inplace <v2v|b2b>]
```

If specified, the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard will perform an in-place upgrade. If v2v is specified, an in-place version to version upgrade is performed. If b2b is specified, an in-place build to build upgrade is performed.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093(v=office.14).aspx

this will do the trick ;)

**EDIT**

The last thing i know of is the configuration cache! as by your reply it looks like regardless what you do it is still taking the old values. If you clear it, it will start all from new and should hopefully get your feature up and running :)

**How to clear SharePoint Configuration Cache?**

> a)     Stop the SharePoint 2010 Timer service on ALL of SharePoint
>   servers in the farm.
>
> b)     Log into your Index server.
>
> c)     Navigate to the directory:
>   C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config\GUID.
>
> d)     Delete all the XML files from the directory.
>
> CAUTION: DELETE ONLY THE .XML FILES, NOT THE .INI FILE. IF YOU
>   DELETED THE .INI file, see item 3.
>
> e)     Open the cache.ini with Notepad and reset the number to 1.
>   Save and close the file.
>
> f)      Start the SharePoint 2010 Timer service on the Index server
>   and wait for XML files to reappear in the directory.
>
> g)     After you see XML files appearing, repeat steps c, d & e on
>   each query server (one server at a  time).
>
> h)     After all of the query servers have all been cleared, repeat
>   steps c, d & e on each of the WFE and application servers in the farm
>   (one server at a time).

http://latenightsp.wordpress.com/2011/03/16/sharepoint-config-cache/

Comment: That is precisely the command that I ran, and that paragraph is precisely the reason I chose this option.
Nevertheless, the error referring to the prior version is what is showing in my logs.

Comment: added an edit to solve your issue ;)

Comment: OK! .. will def. give that a try. THANKS.. I smell impending upvotes

Comment: ok. it prompted me for a -passphrase parameter which I totally don't know.. but I reset it using this info: http://sharepointadam.com/2010/01/21/reset-the-farm-passphrase-in-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Well, I almost got through the update. Looks like it failed on the 3rd of 4 steps. [here's a screenshot of the console](http://code.bkwdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/RunningPSConfig.png) This also has the unfortunate side-effect of killing off my sharepoint web.. it was a development box, so, we're ok. That's why we test these things ;)

Comment: So, now I'm trying to save my upgrade according to [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sushrao/archive/2011/12/01/sharepoint-2010-exception-microsoft-sharepoint-administration-spupdatedconcurrencyexception.aspx) even though his psconfig command is slightly different, he basically got the same kind of error. `stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv Yes` Seems to have saved the day. I ran the above setproperty command and then re-ran your command from the answer above and it has completed successfully this time.

Comment: Still getting the error.. but, I think it's because [I've been changing the AssemblyVersion when I should have been changing the FileVersion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863085/version-sharepoint-wsp)

Comment: Alright.. NOTHING i'm doing is working. I set the assembyversion of my updated DLL back to what my error messages indicate was the preferred version.. I ran Update-SPSolution.. no dice, then I ran psconfig.exe, still not working :-(  Reset IIS, restarted the timer service.. :-(

Comment: ok, iv added a new update at the bottom, i think i know your issue.... i belive its todo with the configuration cache as what you described sounds exactly that :)

Comment: OK. Cleared configuration cache, but, alas - errors persist. Upvoting you for your dogged persistence. I'm sure all your suggestions are correct for *somebody's* scenario.. and I'm sure I have just done something dramatically stupid that I'll eventually realize while trying to sleep at 3 a.m. tomorrow morning

Comment: have you tried Uninstall/Remove Solution and then Add/Install the updated version. Im sure that would have to work! http://blog.incworx.com/blog/sharepoint-administrators-blog/how-to-update-an-existing-sharepoint-2010-solution-quickly-and-easily

Comment: I'm confident, as well, that deactivate,retract,delete,add,etc. would do the job. I was hoping to finally see Update-SPSolution become useful. I was also not wanting to have to add extra engineering to my features that have to be more carefully crafted on a site that was partially instatiated via features (e.g. - if I reactivate the features they need to perform a check and exit early if a list exists already). whereas when the site was new.. the feature simply instatiated the list.