# What happens if feature is already activated and you install new wsp?

Tags: powershell, deployment, feature

Suppose we have deployed a wsp (say webpart) with a feature at site collection level and it is activated.

Then, we change code of the webpart, create a new wsp.

Then, go to central admin->manage farm solutions-> retract and remove the wsp.

Then, install the new wsp using PowerShell - Add solution and PowerShell - Install solution.

Will the webpart get updated, because we had not deactivated the feature earlier, it throws error in PowerShell when we try to enable it as it is already activated at scope of sitecollection.

Comment: You should go with Update-SPSolution instead.

Comment: So I should not retract/remove/deactivate?

Comment: If the wsp name is the same, and you've just made code changes.

Comment: "To upgrade a solution, we specify which solution is to be updated and with which new solution file:

Update-SPSolution –Identity MySharePointSolution.wsp –LiteralPath “D:\Deploy\MySharePointSolution.wsp” –GacDeployment"

Comment: Do we have to give the scope?

Comment: I think not. Check this post out. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/45675/how-do-i-update-an-already-existing-wsp-on-farm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature activated event will not fire again as it is already activated. However, the webpart will get updated because new dll, control templates and other components get deployed properly.