# Upgrade Sharepoint 2013 solution

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, powershell, upgrade

I have a Sharepoint solution installed. I want to install a newer version of the solution as an upgade which I did using :

```
 Update-SPSolution –Identity MySolutionName.wsp –LiteralPath “C:\MySolutionName.wsp” -GACDeployment
```

This command seem to work fine as there are no errors however after I run this, the whole solution becomes uninstalled. Does anyone have any ideas on why this could be or point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: did you run the update-spsolution?

Comment: yes, sorry that word got cut off in my question. When I run the update solution It deploys the new solution but its unsinstalls everything in the solution that was already installed. I guess this is because it is deleting the database? But why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Update-SPSolution command it never works the way it should , Always use the deactivate-retract-delete-add-deploy-activate approach just as if it were a new solution.

[Update-SPSolution does not Deploy Solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36770/update-spsolution-does-not-deploy-solution)

Comment: 1+ to that. Never worked for me, never bother about update-spsolution again.

Comment: Never works as it should? I have never had a problem with it

Comment: Hmm it nevers works for me ,so i stopped using it long back :( MS says : "Use this cmdlet only if a new solution contains the same set of files and features as the deployed solution." Never understood , If there are same set of files/feature why do i need a deployment ?

Comment: The whole remove and redeploy cycle is not always an option.  Clients get really upset when you flush their data to update.

Answer (score 0):

Does the newer version of the solution contain the same set of files/features as the deployed solution?  Can you try an update with a few cosmetic changes to confirm Update-SPSolution is working?

> The Update-SPSolution cmdlet upgrades a deployed SharePoint solution in the farm. Use this cmdlet only if a new solution contains the same set of files and features as the deployed solution. If files and features are different, the solution must be retracted and redeployed by using the Uninstall-SPSolution and Install-SPSolution cmdlets, respectively.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607724(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: yes, all files and features are exactly the same.

Comment: Have you tried deactiving/activating the Feature (Site Settings->Site Collection Features)?  I haven't had any issues with SP-Update, even if I "add files" like a new web part to the solution, but sometimes need to deactive/activate to see the webPart.